# How do I create XML with namespace prefixes?

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

How should I write code in C# to create xml file like this

```
<ymaps:GeoObjectCollection>
    <gml:name>Something</gml:name>
    <gml:featureMembers>
        <ymaps:GeoObject>
            <gml:name>Something</gml:name>
            <gml:description>Something</gml:description>
            <gml:LineString>
                <gml:pos>50.588298 55.145683</gml:pos>
                <gml:pos>50.588290 55.145678</gml:pos>
                <gml:pos>50.588288 55.145678</gml:pos>
            </gml:LineString>
            <ymaps:style>#customStyle1</ymaps:style>
        </ymaps:GeoObject>
```

this yandex's xml file, and it has xsd file on http://maps.yandex.ru/schemas/ymaps/1.x/ymaps.xsd

Answer (score 0):

First familiarize yourself with [XML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML), [XML Namespaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_Namespace), [XML Schemas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_Schema_%28W3C%29) and how to [process XML data in .NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2bcctyt8%28v=vs.80%29). Once you have mastered the basics, use the [XML Schema Definition Tool (Xsd.exe)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) to generate classes from the XSD and use it from within your application.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a demonstration of how to create the desired XML using LINQ to XML. I have created two classes to store the data: `GeoObject` and `Pos`:

```
var geoObjects = new[] {
  new GeoObject {
    Name = "Something",
    Description = "Something",
    Line = new[] {
      new Pos { X = 50.588298M, Y = 55.145683M },
      new Pos { X = 50.588290M, Y = 55.145678M },
      new Pos { X = 50.588288M, Y = 55.145678M }
    },
    Style = "#customStyle1"
  }
};
```

The XML is created using this code:

```
XNamespace ymaps = "http://maps.yandex.ru/ymaps/1.x";
XNamespace gml = "http://www.opengis.net/gml";
var xElement = new XElement(
  ymaps + "GeoObjectCollection",
  new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "ymaps", ymaps),
  new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "gml", gml),
  new XElement(gml + "name", "Something"),
  new XElement(gml + "featureMembers",
    geoObjects.Select(
      geoObject => new XElement(
        ymaps + "GeoObject",
        new XElement(gml + "name", geoObject.Name),
        new XElement(gml + "description", geoObject.Description),
        new XElement(gml + "LineString",
          geoObject.Line.Select(
            pos => new XElement(
              gml + "pos",
              String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0} {1}", pos.X, pos.Y)
            )
          )
        ),
        new XElement(ymaps + "style", geoObject.Style)
      )
    )
  )
);
```

If you write out `xElement` you get the following XML:

```
<ymaps:GeoObjectCollection xmlns:ymaps="http://maps.yandex.ru/ymaps/1.x" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml">
  <gml:name>Something</gml:name>
  <gml:featureMembers>
    <ymaps:GeoObject>
      <gml:name>Something</gml:name>
      <gml:description>Something</gml:description>
      <gml:LineString>
        <gml:pos>50.588298 55.145683</gml:pos>
        <gml:pos>50.588290 55.145678</gml:pos>
        <gml:pos>50.588288 55.145678</gml:pos>
      </gml:LineString>
      <ymaps:style>#customStyle1</ymaps:style>
    </ymaps:GeoObject>
  </gml:featureMembers>
</ymaps:GeoObjectCollection>
```